# Change the keyboard type of UITextField in UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I created a UIAlertView with its `alertViewStyle` set to `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput`.

I want to change the keyboard type, but not by adding a subview.

My Code：

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"a" message:@"b" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"aaa", nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;  
[alert show];
```

Comment: @nsgulliver，@nsgulliver,now，I expressed that clear?

Comment: You want to change the keyboard type? or just want to present keyboard in inputStyle?

Comment: you can go for a custom textfield option (will added to the alertview with add subview method).If you want i can provide you the code.

Comment: ye,I Want change the keyboard type,But not [alert addsubView:XX]..

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If You want to present the Input Style, First of all implement the [UIAlertViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html) in your class.

Secondly when you presenting the alertView set the delegate to self.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"a" message:@"b" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"aaa", nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;  
[alert show];'
```

If you want to change the keyboard type for particular field then do like this

**e.g** for 1st field, it will make the keyboard numeritc.

```
[[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
[[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] becomeFirstResponder];
```

**UPDATE for iOS 8.0 Swift**

From ios 8.0 onward  `UIAlertView` is deprecated so you might need to use `UIAlertController`

```
 var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Your msg", 
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, 
              handler:yourHandler))

        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({(textField: UITextField!) in
            textField.placeholder = "Password"
            textField.secureTextEntry = true  // setting the secured text for using password
            textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default
        })
```

Comment: okok，Thank you very much..My English is not very good，Sorry..